# Dart shared preferences not saving to disk

Tags: flutter, dart

I've spent hours debugging this and can't find anything wrong with my code. I am on a MacOS, Big Sur, using VSCode and iOS emulator.

The shared preferences bloc returns that the storage was a success, but when I look on disk where the directory storage is, there is no file or anything there. This was just working the other day, but I did update flutter master. I downgraded to flutter beta but am having the same problem.

Does anyone see anything wrong with this or having a similar issue?

```java
 @override
  Future<Either<Failure, UserEntity>> putStoredUserLoginModel() async {
    final SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final userMember = getUserMember();

    await sp.setInt('foo', 1);
    final userModel = userMember.toJson().toString();
    print('PUTING: $userModel');
    final bool notFailed = await sp.setString('userModel', userModel);
    if (notFailed) {
      return const Right(UserEmpty());
    } else {
      return Left(CacheFailure());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is it working on a real device?

Comment: Thanks for the question @Nicks101  It caused me to look in other areas. I'm not sure the fix, as I did a few things. But it's working now. I tried to run it on my phone and it wouldn't. So fired it up in Xcode which had some errors I had to fix, then removed my ~/.pub* directory. It's working now.